# How to write dimension filter in GA4 Reports Builder for Google Analytics™ addon for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics

Until recently, I used Google Analitycs integration with Google Spreadsheets using the official add-on. Now due to the move to GA4, I need to change the add-on to GA4 Reports Builder for Google Analytics™. I have a problem, I have no idea how to write a dimmension filter to show "eventCount" for each "eventName" filtering out only "Organic Search" traffic source.

Using Query Explorer, the following query works:

```
"""dimensionFilter"":{
""filter"":{
""stringFilter"":{
""matchType"":""CONTAINS""
""value"":""Organic""
}
""fieldName"":""sessionDefaultChannelGroup""
}
}"
```

But when I paste it into the report configuration sheet into the "Dimension Filters" field, this filter is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no documentation for filters with the add-on mentioned.

Try the **GA4 Magic Reports** addon for Google Sheets, you can setup filters, sorting, editing reports and schedule reports: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/ga4_magic_reports/6532356327